# Use of completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData) when doing a background refresh in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing background refresh in my app. To test the app I have this in my AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {



    NSLog(@"did a background refresh");
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);



}
```

I tested it on the simulator and it works fine. I am unsure of what the use of `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);` Why do I need to call this and what can I use it for? I understand that it can be:

```
UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData - Called when new content has been fetched, and the application has been updated.
UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData - Called when the fetch for new content went through, but no content is available.
UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed - Useful for error handling, this is called when the fetch was unable to go through.
```

However I don't understand why I have to call it and how it's useful. Any pointers on this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to call this to let iOS know what the result of your background fetch was. It uses this information to schedule future background fetches.

If you neglect to do this, future background fetches may be delayed by the OS.

**Update**: The consequences of not calling this handler might include terminating your app altogether.

Comment: Does it not also force the UI to update before the push is opened too?

Comment: AFAIK it will not update your UI per se; but since you typically changed your UI yourself as a response to the new data, it also notifies the system that this has happened. This will, for example, affect the scaled-down image of your app in the task switcher.

Comment: I noticed that when I receive a notification no matter what the status of the completion handler is it is executing code from the current view controller (even though the app is in the background). Not totally sure what code it's executing though.

Comment: seems like it is executing viewWillAppear but the app is not even showing

Comment: Yes, it does that to create that little snapshot (drawing your UI into a separate graphics context.)

Comment: can a table refresh be done in the background ie [tableView reloadData] and refreshed? I've seen examples online of setting UILabels and the UIView refreshing but none for tables.

Comment: Speculating here, but I think `[tableview reloadddata]` just invalidates the content and causes `-setNeedsDisplay:YES`, and the table view will redraw at the next chance it gets (either when going foreground, or when the snapshot is created.)